# Dynamic conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a stored procedure and would like to know if its possible to build up a dynamic `where` condition based on a parameter.

Lets say I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Users
```

Now, I have a parameter called `@username`, which I would like to use to build up a dynamic `where` condition (which through my program might be 1 or more conditions). To achieve something like that I use the following statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Users
@username -- where this parameter might hold a condition string such as "Where usr_Username = 5 and usr_first_name like '%Frank%' etc
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Not in T-SQL itself; you can build that SELECT statement in your front-end language (C#, VB.NET or whatever) and send it to SQL Server once it's complete, or you can use dynamic SQL inside a T-SQL statement to build up your query as a string and then "execute" that string - but you cannot just "parametrize" part of yuor T-SQL query like this....

Comment: You can do it with string-building (like several folks below have demonstrated), but just a word of caution -- avoid dynamic sql if you have any choice in the matter -- it's very much a pain-in-the-neck to write, maintain, upgrade, troubleshoot, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You're going to have to break into dynamic sql for this.

it would run something like this:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = '
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_Users
    WHERE ' + @username

exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain I understand you, but if my understanding is correct, you can do the following (NOTICE: injection vulnerable)

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(500) = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_users ' + @username

EXEC @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, this is not going to work. You're going to need to generate the script you want to execute and use the exec command.

Answer (score 0):

You are really **not** supposed to be concatenating SQL keywords and parameters into one single string as shown in some of the responses above for reasons of opening the doors to **SQL injection** (One of the contributors actually called it out. That's a wise Warning!).

Instead, you are supposed to **parameterize** your SQL and execute the system SP **sp_executesql**.

A very good code example is shown in this [StackOverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329823/add-where-clauses-to-sql-dynamically-programmatically).