# Building a WHERE clause programmatically, then passing it into SQL as a parameter

Tags: c#, sql, where-clause, parameterized, clause

On my asp.net project, there are instances where a server side filter function in C# is building an SQL `WHERE` clause, then passing it into an SQL stored procedure for example,

Filter produces a string variable with a value like “`WHERE Qty < 5 AND Price > 10`”.

The relevant part of the Stored Procedure is like:

```
Exec (‘
    Select Name, Location
    From Users
    + ‘@passedInWhereClause’
‘)
```

As you can see, we have to do an `EXEC` command on a string built with the passed in variable containing the `where` clause that was generated by C# code on the server side.
I would really like a way to eliminate the `EXEC` and make the SQL code look more professional, instead of a giant string wrapped with an `EXEC`. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Here be SQL injection dragons...

Comment: [This is another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945461/t-sql-dynamic-where-condition) like yours. The short answer is NO.

Comment: Have you considered using EF or Linq-To-SQL to do this instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider optional parameters, example

```
WHERE (@Type = NULL OR @Type = '' OR @Type = Type)
```

This allows you to pass a NULL or blank to the SP to ignore the where clause, or you pass a value to have the where clause applied.

Comment: We actually do optional parameters elsewhere in our code. This should work here as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there is not a better way to do this, as you are building Dynamic SQL to execute.

If you want to do it better, then don't run Dynamic SQL.

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)